# how to style a particular wordpress sidebar widget

Tags: wordpress-theming

I have sidebar widgets visible when I open a post in my website. But since the website is bilingual, some of them are supposed to be right aligned while others left aligned.

Is this possible? If I knew which function is generating the content for sidebar HTML, perhaps I could achieve this but I don't know where that function is, if it existed.

Answer (score 0):

umm... kinda got it working.

I made the following changes to the file:
*wp-includes\widgets\class-wp-widget-recent-posts.php*

It had the following code:

```
<ul>
        <?php while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php get_the_title() ? the_title() : the_ID(); ?></a>
            <?php if ( $show_date ) : ?>
                <span class="post-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
```

I then changed it to:

```
<ul>
        <?php while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post(); ?>

            <?php
            if (strpos(get_the_title(), 'a') !== false) {
                echo '<li class="engwidget">';
            }else{
                echo '<li class="localwidget">';
            } 
            ?>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php get_the_title() ? the_title() : the_ID(); ?></a>
            <?php if ( $show_date ) : ?>
                <span class="post-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
```

I've achieved what I wanted but no idea if this is by any means a right way to do so.